# Accessing bitmap memory info using bytes

Tags: c#, java, bitmap, byte

(I've made three posts in the last week on SO regarding a Java project I'm working on. I feel guilty, but what the hell, your answers are amazing.)

Here's a chunk of code in C#:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...
    
int dstStride = bitmap.Stride;
        
byte* bdst = (byte*)bitmap.Scan0;
```

I want to make an equivalent algorithm in Java. I'm beginning to think this is impossible, based on [other, similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735743/how-to-access-memory-location-in-java).

I can actually replicate the stride info of my bitmap, but of course, that `byte*` is nigh impossible to reproduce. What happens later is that there's a `for` loop that manipulates the bitmap image, a la:

```
bdst[x * 3 + y * dstStride + 2] = (byte)(alpha * bsrc[dx * 3 + L * srcStride + 2]);
```

(x & y are iterators in a loop)

Naturally I'm unable to simply make bdst a byte array because that doesn't make sense. [According to this totally awesome article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx), Scan0 is "[t]he address in memory of the fixed data array."

And judging by the above SO post, this is not possible in Java. Confirm / deny?

Comment: Not sure why can't you treat bdst as a byte array? That's exactly what it is. C# Bitmap class is a wrapper over native bitmap object that obviously represents internal image data as pointer to first memory location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a direct pointer to memory in Java. This is obviously by design.

However you can get an array of pixels from an Image using the [PixelGrabber](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html) class. Or, if you have a [BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), you can work with the [Raster](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) directly. This may help you achieve your goal without accessing memory directly.