# getting the memory location for a java byte array using sun.misc.unsafe

Tags: java, arrays, unsafe

I want to pass the memory location of a byte array to a jni call so that the array does not have to be copied. There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735743/how-to-access-memory-location-in-java) that hints this is possible with sun.misc.Unsafe. Is there an example of how this can be done?

The use case is that I have a BufferedImage and I have a OpenGL method that takes in a pointer. I know that the obvious thing to do is to allocate a direct bytebuffer but I want to save on the copy.

Comment: Never use Unsafe. JNI doesn't need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if at all feasible, migrate to JNA, it's much more user friendly (doesn't require you to compile c files)

If you want to pass data directly to native code, don't use an array, but use a `ByteBuffer` instead. To create it, use `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` (the direct part signifies that it doesn't use an internal array but 'direct' memory.) JNI and JNA should automatically detect this and pass the pointer to the native library.

Comment: How did you obtain the bufferedimage? Isn't it possible to load an image using the native lib? (e.g. LWJGL has STBImage)

Comment: yeah, I went with the alternative method of creating a DataBuffer wrapping a ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading, it seems that it's not the best [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820369/1291986). I ended up using this to pass the native data to the `BufferedImage`.

```
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class DirectDataBuffer extends DataBuffer {
    protected ByteBuffer directByteBuffer;

    public DirectDataBuffer(ByteBuffer directByteBuffer) {
        super(TYPE_BYTE, directByteBuffer.capacity());
        this.directByteBuffer = directByteBuffer;   
    }

    public int getElem(int bank, int i) {
        return directByteBuffer.get(i);
    }

    public void setElem(int bank, int i, int val) {
        directByteBuffer.put(i, (byte)val);
    }

    public ByteBuffer getDirectByteBuffer() {
        return directByteBuffer;
    }
}
```